# Java - How to get class calling method

Tags: java, api, exception, plugins, configuration

I am currently working on an API for a software so my users can create plugins and change the software without modifying the program itself and allow users without programming knowledge to change how to software runs as well. Much like [Bukkit](http://bukkit.org) and [Spigot](http://spigotmc.org) You see, I am trying to get the class calling the method so I can get the plugin.yml. Which, I know how to do. But its in the format of a String. And since the class is not inside the program jar/project. It will throw a ClassNotFoundException. So does anyone here know how to get the class calling a method in the form of a Class object?

Comment: SuperstarGamer - Trent: Kindly provide some relevant snippet of your code so that we can have a clear ider of your question.

Comment: Alright, will do. Normally I do provide code. But I had no idea. I will have it posted after school (I'm 13)

Answer (score 1):

One way of obtaining the calling class which I have never used, but I have seen the java runtime using, (for example, in `java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger()`) involves `@CallerSensitive` and `Reflection.getCallerClass()`. You could give them a try.

That having been said, I am not sure what is the problem with invoking `Class.forName()` to obtain a class given a class name.  I do not see how the fact that the other class is in a different JAR file could possibly affect you; the other class is known to the JVM, (obviously, since it is calling your class,) so `Class.forName()` should work.